# When My iOS App enters the lock screen state, after about 10 minutes later, the program will be killed.

Tags: ios

When My iOS App enters the lock screen state, after about 10 minutes later, the program will be killed. how to do was not killed when my App enter lock Screen State.

Comment: I don't understand "how to do was not killed when my App enter lock Screen State."... Could you update your question with more information?

Answer (score 0):

In your Apps Info.plist, add the Key called "Required Background Modes" (an array) and add one or more items with the reason your app must stay in background.

The info.plist file is usually in the Xcode group called "Supporting Files"